# Tear up - definition Cambridge

Tags: verbs

I was checking out some phrasal verbs of the verb **Tear** in *Cambridge Dictionary*, it shows all definitions of one single word, and my question is related to the phrasal verb **Tear up**, which means:

> To almost cry due to a strong emotion that is being experienced.

Well, That's how Cambridge defines it and also provides some examples. This was the example provided by cambridge:

*She teared up as the award was presented to her.*

Why is it **teared** and not **tore**, since the past tense of the verb **Tear** is: **Tore**?

Is using "teared or tore" optional?

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/tear-up

Comment: The past tense of that definition of *Tear* is not *Tore*. One sounds like **Teer** and the other sounds like **Tare**. This is probably one of the most confusing parts of learning English. Two words that are spelled the same, but are pronounced and defined differently.

Comment: You have the wrong verb. *Tear*, pronounced like *wear*, means to rip. *Tear up* is pronounced like *year up*, and it means to begin to cry (eyes get wet).

Comment: @Hank - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/tear

**Tear** - **Tore** and **Torn**.

Comment: @Drew - I think there is only one verb, besides, it is listed in the phrasal verbs of the word **Tear** - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/tear

Comment: Well, you think wrong. You can *tear up* a sheet of paper (pronounced like *wear up*. And you can *tear up* (pronounced like *year up*). The latter is a completely different verb, and it does not take an object. See [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tear-up).

Comment: @Drew - It has nothing to do with my question, Sir. Did you read what I wanted? I want to know why the example provided by Cambridge is written with **teared** and not **tore** which is the past form of the verb **tear**.
I think I understood what you intended to say, yes, there is one phrasal verb which means to tear something into a lot of small little pieces - *She tore her contract up*, but this isn't what I want to know, there is another phrasal verb.

Comment: Read @Hank's helpful answer. Or read the comments again. Live and learn.

Comment: @Haseo You are mistaken. The past tense of *tear* is *tore*, but the past tense of *tear* is *teared*.  Hope that's completely clore up now.

Comment: @tchrist: ;-)!!

Comment: @tchrist - It was clear, but I also want to know why this is listed in the list of phrasal verbs of the word - **Tear**

Comment: @Haseo Here, let's try again this time with Latin: intransitive *to /tɪr/ up* is to become **lachrymous**, but transitive *to /ter/ something up* is to **mutilate** it.  Claro?

Comment: @tchrist - Ainda não. Mas minha questão já foi respondida, obrigado, anyway. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing two different words.

> #### [1. Tear](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tear)
>
> (scroll down the page)
>
> *[tair]*
>
> - To pull apart or in pieces by force, especially so as to leave ragged or irregular edges.

The past tense version of definition 1 is **Tore**.

> #### [2. Tear](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tear)
>
> *[teer]*
>
> - To fill up and overflow with tears, as the eyes

The past tense version of definition 2 is **Teared**.

***Teared up*** is using the 2nd definition.

Comment: Now you were clear, there are two different words, but I'm still confused why it was listed in the phrasal verbs of the word **Tear** - the one that means to rip.

Comment: +1.  All the more confusing, at least in print, given that one can tear up a letter from an ex, and tear up over it at the same time.

Comment: @Haseo What is the link to the page giving you phrasal verbs? Perhaps it's giving you the phrasal verbs of definition 2 as opposed to the one you were expecting, definition 1?

Comment: @Hank - I was browsing through the word **Tear** - the one which means: Rip something, and in the phrasal verbs related to the word "Tear" was: **Tear up**

Comment: @Haseo If that is true, then the page is at fault. It was probably just an unknown mistake.

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tear-up_1.  Note that *both* meanings of the word tear have a phrasal variant with the preposition up- Tear up (rip apart) a piece of paper, tear up (get wet eyes) due to emotion.

Comment: The other definition would be http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tear-up_2

Comment: @cobaltduck 'both meanings of the word _tear_ ...' is erroneous. As [these three dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tear) show, these are different words, homographs (but not homophones).